# Postgresql - perform function inside another function and resume next on error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have 2 functions in Postgresql 9.3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Function_A(param_id integer, param_name text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

my_id integer;
my_name text;

BEGIN

    my_id = somefunction(param_id);
    my_name = somefunction(param_name);
    insert into tableA(id, name) values (my_id, my_name);

END

  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION Function_A(integer, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Function_B(param_id bigint, param_name text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    insert into tableC(id, name) values (param_id, param_name);

        perform Function_A(param_id, param_name);


END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION Function_B(bigint, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

So, I have problem, when Function A returns error, Function B does not insert data into table C.

I want something like this:

If Perform Function A returns error resume next, so my Function B can insert data into table C and continue without problem.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are the 2 functions being called? Are both the calls part of same transaction?

Comment: Yes, it is the same transaction. And I want to continue with transaction even if the Function A returns error.

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual SQL code, we cannot actually help you that much. If you want to force a function to continue without caring about errors, then you can use SQL exception syntax

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- keep looping
END;
```

Comment: I edited my post, but I am new here and don't know how to format these functions to look nice.